# React portfolio on GitHub Pages: 404 File Not Found

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment

So after working for weeks on my portfolio using React, I was ready to deploy it on GitHub Pages. But all I get after deployment to https://ben-brunner.github.io/Reactfolio/ is

> 404 File Not Found

My repo : https://github.com/ben-brunner/Reactfolio

My homepage in the package.json file:

```
"homepage": "https://ben-brunner.github.io/Reactfolio/"
```

I've got the predeploy and deploy lines in the package as well.
I've been trying things for hours, help guys...

Answer (score 0):

GitHub only has [three options](https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site) for a publishing source for GitHub Pages:

- `master` branch root
- **docs/** folder on the `master` branch
- `gh-pages` branch

Your repo has your built files in a directory named *public/*. If you rename that to **docs/** and configure to serve from there, your site should work.

Comment: Thanks for your help, one thing I do not understand though is why all the tutorials on "How to deploy a React app on GH Pages" get their projects online without problem. I didn't move my files, create-react-app always organizes them that way, having to rename and reroute my public folder sounds more complicated than it should be according to, well, everyone else on the Web haha

Comment: It is more a GitHub Pages thing. If you use something like [Vercel](https://vercel.com/) or [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/), those are more configurable and so don't have the same restrictions. Googling for a tutorial, if you found [this one](https://dev.to/yuribenjamin/how-to-deploy-react-app-in-github-pages-2a1f), it definitely leaves some things out. One thing is that package [gh-pages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages) uses the setup where your GitHub Pages site is served from a branch named `gh-pages`. Again, you need to configure you repo to look at that branch name.

Comment: Thanks, for those reading this: if you use react-router-dom in your project, your React app will never work on GH pages... Not supported. I went with Firebase.